# Is there any way to validate the path by using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, validation, path, aws-api-gateway

I am using serverless framework for the backend. Use AWS.

my severless.yml like this.

```
functions:
  getBrand:
    handler: functions/brand/getBrand.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: ${self:custom.BASE_URL}/brand/{brandUuid}
          private: true
          method: get
          reqValidatorName: onlyBody
          request: 
            parameters: 
             paths: 
                brandUuid: true
```

I want to validate the brandUuid in the gateway.

After passing verification, call my aws lambda.

Comment: If you really need that feature, you can add custom authorizer to your lambda and do this validation inside of the authorizer. However, as I don't know the context it is hard for me to understand why you don't want to do validation inside of the getBrand.handler itself. It's the right place to do that: eg. you can query DynamoDB to see if such brandUUID actually exists and return 404 or 403 respectively. 
Custom authorizers are meant for operations orthogonal to your getBrand.handler (eg. authorization using tokens etc), but checking uuid for existence IMHO seems 2 b concern of handler itself