# How to validate or filter a wildcard in path for http endpoints in Serverless and AWS API gateway before the process triggs the lambda function?

Tags: api, validation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, endpoint

I have the following http path `devices/{sn}` in a Serverless-AWS APIgateway API. The wildcard `sn` is a 15 digits [A-Z0-9] pattern.

In the API today any string that is not recognized as a valid path is redirected to this end-point. Ex: `devices/test` goes to `devices/{sn}`, `devices/bla` goes to `devices/{sn}` and so on. All those strings will query the database and return null because there is no such `sn` in the table. I could create a validation process inside the lambda to avoid the unnecessary database query. But I want to save lambda resource and I would like to validate before call the lambda.

This is what I have today for this endpoint:

```
- http:
        path: devices/{sn}
        method: GET
        private: false
        cors: true
        authorizer: ${file(env.yml):${self:provider.stage}.authorizer}
        request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                sn: true
```

How can I setup this validation or filter in `Serverless.yml`?

In fact it should be a very straight-forward functionality of AWS/Serverless.

Let's say we have the following scenario: `myPath/{id}`. In this case id is a integer (a pk in a table). If I type `myPath/blabla` it will trigg the lambda. The system will spend resource. It shoul have a kind of previous validation - trig the endpoint only if the `{id} === integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433030/is-there-any-way-to-validate-the-path-by-using-serverless-framework)
According to the post and from my experience, No, I don't think you can perform validation in api-gateway level.

Comment: yes, it is the same but there is no asnwer, unfirtunately.